# Time function in Azure Data Factory - Expression Builder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, expressionbuilder

I only need to take the time part from the 'Timestamp type source attribute' and load it into a dedicated SQL pool table (Time datatype column). But I don't find a time function within the expression builder in ADF, is there a way I can do it?

-What did I do?
-I took the time part from the source attribute using substring and then tried to load the same into the destination table, when I do the destination table inserted null values as the column at the destination table is set to time datatype.

[image: Express Builder]

[image: Mapping]

[image: Data Preview]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this and got the same issue. The following is a demonstration of the same. I have a table called `mydemo` as shown below.

```
CREATE  TABLE [dbo].[mydemo]
(
id int  NOT  NULL,
my_date date,
my_time time
)
WITH
(
DISTRIBUTION = HASH (id),
CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
GO
```

The following is my source data in my dataflow.

[image]

- `time` is not a recognized datatype in azure dataflow (`date and timestamp` are accepted). Therefore, dataflow fails to convert `string` (*substring(<timestamp_col>,12,5)*) into `time` type.
- For better understanding, you can load your sink table as source in dataflow. The time column will be read as `1900-01-01 12:34:56` when time value in the table row is `12:34:56`.

```
#my table row
insert  into mydemo values(200,'2022-08-18','12:34:56')
```

[image]

- So, instead of using `substring(<timestamp_col>,12,5)` to return **00:01**, use `concat('1900-01-01 ',substring(<timestamp_col>,12,8))` which returns **1900-01-01 00:01:00**.

[image]

- Configure the sink, mapping and look at the resulting data in `data preview`. Now, azure dataflow will be able to successfully insert the values and give desired results.

[image]

- The following is the output after successful insertion of record into dedicated pool table.

[image]

**NOTE:** You can construct valid yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss as a value using concat('yyyy-MM-dd ',substring(<timestamp_col>,12,8)) in place of 1900-01-01 hh:mm:ss in derived column transformation.